# Array keeps coming back as Nil from Parse

Tags: swift, parse-server

I'm trying to determine if a Parse value has been defined and then if the object has a value assign the Array to my arr variable.

But it keeps coming back as nil. And yes, there is a value inside blockedUsers which is a Parse Array.

```
if let blockedUser2 = currentUser?["blockedUsers"] as! [String]{
    let arr = currentUser?["blockedUsers"] as! [String]

    print(arr)
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You don't need `arr`: if the condition is matched, you can access `blockedUser2`. You are already unwrapping it safely with the if let declaration.

About your issue... could you provide some more code? Where do you get your `currentUser` array from?

Comment: This is where i get currentUser from  :     let currentUser = PFUser.current()

Comment: When I do the same with  if let blockedUser2 = currentUser?["username"] as! String that works.  I don'T know why but why but anytime I try on a Parse array value it comes back Nil but on a regular String value it's fine.

Comment: As I wrote, paste more code in your question. Debugging one line of code at a time is nonsense.